# Would optimizing a CSS3 animation without H/W acceleration off make it run faster on GPU afterwards?

Tags: javascript, css, webkit, css-transitions, css-animations

It sounds like a strange question at first - but bear with me.

I wrote a setTimeout-based benchmark (similar to [stats.js](https://github.com/mrdoob/stats.js/)) - the idea was to have something to compare how an animation is performing under different conditions (like adding to it different CSS3 properties). For (simple) example I'd have something with rotation and box-shadow animated, then I'd remove rotation in the second run and box-shadow in the third run. Afterwards I'd have 3 benchmark numbers to compare how each of those animations is performing.

This works well as long as the animation is not GPU-accelerated (for obvious reasons i.e. H/W acceleration removes the animation from the page's single-process structure).

But that also brings me to the million dollar question - if I optimize something to run better without GPU-acceleration does that mean that same optimized animation would run better (either faster or with less memory usage) with GPU-acceleration turned on? Or do different rules apply?

Let me give you a simpler example. CSS3 box-shadow will kill performance in almost any animation. In simpler cases you can augment performance by replacing CSS3 box-shadow with a rasterized (PNG?) image of a similar shadow. However with GPU-on, the benefits of that are not as apparent to the naked eye because both animations would appear run almost equally fast (because again - I can't track performance changed with GPU-on). So again - do the same rules apply with GPU-on and -off?

My initial impulse was - once something is optimized - it runs better no matter GPU-on or -off. But like I mentioned in a comment below (and please correct me if I understand this wrong), but a hardware-accelerated element is cached as a pre-rendered raster texture on the GPU. If thats true - why would it then make any difference if my shadow is a CSS3 box shadow or an image-base PNG shadow? I mean both of these elements would with GPU-on just be turned into a rasterized texture anyway right? So my optimization would not make any more sense with GPU-on? (unless if there is a difference somehow in memory usage again...)

Comment: "Do the same rules apply with GPU-on and -off?" : short answer no. The GPU will be extremely fast in very specific areas, and this means the rules *can* change drastically depending on what *exactly* you're doing. It can even change depending on what GPU is available (is it DX9 or DX11 compatible for example). I think unless you have very specific examples you want verified there's little the community can do to answer your question here, however, I would point out that your application performing well without HW acceleration means it'll almost certainly perform well with HW acceleration.

Comment: Thanks - yeah, this is not as much for a specific application as much as it is for a research paper :)

When I was building my benchmark, the idea was to see not only how different CSS3 properties affect an animation, but also compare programmatically the same animation for example with CSS3 translate, sprites, canvas or SVG - running across devices and browsers. However, again I'm only able to benchmark that with GPU-off (programmatically). But the question is - if (hypothetically) sprites beat SVG with GPU-off - do they still beat SVG with GPU-on? (because both are now too fast to tell)

Comment: I know that all of these ways of doing animation have different conditions - but lets say you try very hard to recreate almost identical conditions between them (the same number of executions/keyframes/frames per second, etc. etc.)...

Answer (score 1):

Yes, absolutely. Look [here](http://www.html5rocks.com/en/tutorials/speed/html5/) for a little bit about what GPU acceleration does and does not affect. But the general idea is, yes, it will keep most of your optimizations. Now, *how much* a given optimization will affect performance after GPU offloading, in a relative sense.. That's a tough question to answer.

Comment: Hi Phillip - thanks for your answer. My initial instinct was like yours that if you optimize something with GPU-off it would be still be better than the original with GPU-on. But if I understand it correctly (and I'm not an expert on OpenGL and such), the element your hardware-accelerating gets cached as a raster texture on the GPU. If that is true - why would it matter then if I provide a drop-shadow as a CSS3 property or a PNG image? Both of those are converted into a texture anyway and cached by the GPU right? Thats the background on why I asked the question here ;-)

Comment: @Michael Ah, I probably should have read it a little better the first time. Well, in this case, it's not going to be a huge difference (though it will make a little difference, since building a texture from a PNG is less expensive than calculating a computed style and mapping it to a texture). I think the main idea you're on to is whether doing a little bit of the GPU's work before offloading it will benefit you. The answer to that question is "I doubt it". On the other hand, though, trying to give the GPU "easier" data to work with (like this case) will help.